# Swift how to print optional string

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

Maybe a very basic question, but haven't found a good answer without a lot of extra code basically:

```
var item: String?
print(item) //works as expected
print("Item: "+item) //compile error
```

I'd like to achieve the second form without extra variables or expressions/code in some way?

Comment: Look up "string interpolation" ...

Comment: Unwrap it with `if let` or `guard let`. You could do a force unwrap, but in case of nullity, it will crashes. There is also the `String(describing:)` or String interpolation.

Comment: Very good, thanks, so basically you can use print("Item: \(item)"). New to swift so thats new to me!

Comment: with a backward slash (which stackoverflow removed)

Comment: Why does it take five people to mark this question as duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it like

```
print("Item: \(item)")
```

The way to write it in swift is like this.

And as you are sure about the existing value inside, so it can be

```
print("Item: \(item!)")
```

if in some other case, where you are not sure if the value exists or not then you can use if let

```
if let item = item {
    print("Item: \(item)")
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, yeah thats what I was looking for

Comment: Your most welcome @breakline

Answer (score 1):

I'd reccommend using [string interpolation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html#ID292).

You have 4 options for actually unwrapping the optional:

1. Checking against `nil`. You can make sure that your optional is non-`nil`, and if so, force-unwrap it.

   ```
   if optional != nil {
       print(optional!)
   }
   ```
2. `if-let` or `guard-let` (optional binding). This checks to see if the optional is non-`nil`, and if so, provides it, unwrapped, inside the `if` statement.

   ```
   if let nonOptional = optional {
       print(nonOptional)
   }
   ```
3. Force-unwrapping. This acts normally if your optional is not `nil`, but crashes if it is `nil`. For that reason, this approach is not recommended.

   ```
   print(optional!)
   ```
4. Default values. This approach uses the value of your variable if it is non-`nil`, or the provided *default value* if it was `nil`.

   ```
   print(optional ?? "Optional was nil!")
   ```

For your specific scenario, I would either this:

```
print("Item: \(item ?? "Item was nil!")")
```

or this:

```
if let item = item {
    print("Item: \(item)")
} else {
    print("Item was nil!")
}
```

Keep in mind that you don't need an `else` clause if you don't want to print if `item` is `nil`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try the following line

```
if let item = item {
    print(String.init(format: "Item: %@", item))
}
```

**or**

```
if let item = item {
   print("Item: \(item)") 
}
```